# how does `subsample` parameter work in boosting algorithms like xgboost and lightgbm?

Tags: machine-learning, sampling, boosting, lightgbm

From what I know, both of them are sequential learners and only the 1st tree in the sequence gets built on the data and all the following trees that get built are to correct the mistakes of previous tree, hence improving the performance or decreasing the bias.

`subsample` parameters in [xgboost](https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/stable/python/python_api.html#xgboost.XGBRegressor) and [lightgbm](https://lightgbm.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pythonapi/lightgbm.LGBMRegressor.html#lightgbm.LGBMRegressor) dictates the percentage of rows used per tree building.

So, with this context, if `subsample` is set to 0.75, first tree gets built with 75% of the data and all the following trees will focus on correcting mistakes. So, what happens to the remaining 25% of the data? will another set of sequential tress be built parallelly? or am I missing something here or got something wrong?

Comment: `Subsample ratio of the training instances. Setting it to 0.5 means that XGBoost would randomly sample half of the training data prior to growing trees. and this will prevent overfitting. Subsampling will occur once in every boosting iteration.`

Comment: yes, if `subsample` is set to 0.5, for the first boosting iteration, only 50% of the randomly sampled data will be used. i want to know how the remaining 50% of the data will be used? will it be in another parallel boosting iteration? or how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That 25% of the data is unused by that learner (i.e. that iteration) of the XGBoost model (assuming `subsample=0.75`). This is normal, what they do via the `subsample` argument is to implement [bagging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bootstrap_aggregating) by subsampling once in every boosting iteration. This means that, as you described, a portion of the data is not used *by that specific base-learner* during the $i$-th iteration. In the $i+1$-th iteration, sub-sampling of the *whole* dataset is performed once again.

Through bagging (or more formally bootstrap aggregation) we practically bootstrap our estimator and allow ourselves to have a more robust overall result - think of it as estimating the sample mean via bootstrapping; just the "mean" here is the "expected prediction for each item" in our sample instead of a single "expected prediction for the sample's central tendency".

And note that irrespective of the subsampling proportion we might use (e.g. 10%), we can always provide estimates for all (i.e. 100%) of our sample items. Some will be out-of-sample of course and some in-sample. In that way, we can also estimate error gradients for all our sample items if needed.

Comment: thanks @usεr11852. your answer has created more questions than it answered, at my side. how many base-learners does, say, a run(`.fit()`) of xgboost will have and what parameter controls that? from, what i know, ONE base learner starts by fitting to the data and all the following train iterations will be fit on the previous one's residuals and this continues for `num_iterations` number of times. if there will be another fresh base-learner, fit again, with another randomly sub-sampled 75% of the data from previous base-learner, will that fit `num_iterations` number of times too?

Comment: Haha, sometimes that is the case. I am glad I can help. The number of base-learners is controlled by the `num_round`/`num_iterations` argument. In boosting, each iteration fits a new base learner. That base learner itself is (in the simple cases) a tree. There are no iterations involved in that tree fitting, just recursive partitioning that is controlled by the relevant parameters (e.g. `subsample`, `max_depth`, etc.).

Comment: more confustion and more questions now. in my comment, by `num_iterations`, i meant the argument `n_estimators`.
1. C failed to find any parameter called `num_round` in xgboost and lightgbm's python API docs. 2. "In boosting, each iteration fits a new base learner.". in this, is 'iteration' the same thing as `n_estimators`? 2.1 if yes, will the num of base-learners be equal to `n_estimators`?

Comment: 3. "There are no iterations involved in that tree fitting,". which tree? the base-learner? yes, i meant, this tree will be sequentially improved by fitting to it's residuals in the following iterations. or i may have got this wrong.

Comment: 1. The XGBoost docs are messed up at the moment the parameter obviously exists, the LightGBM [ones](https://lightgbm.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Parameters.html) defo have them just Control+F `num_b`. 2. Yes. 2.1. Yes. 3. Yes, the base learner. But the tree itself won't be "improved", the overall boosting ensemble performance will be improved.

Comment: 1. in lightgbm docs, `num_iterations`, `num_trees`, `num_boost_round`, `n_estimators` are the same thing and explanation on this parameter is "number of boosting iterations". so, is that the number of trees(or base-learners) that get built? or the improvements in overall boosting?
2. thanks for busting the myth. i have been under the assmption that the tree itself will be improved, the splits of tress, binning for a leaf etc,. will you be able tell me how "the overall boosting ensemble performance will be improved" or point me to any blog/resource that may help me learn more about this?!

Comment: 3. And the number of base-learners fit will be decided by the parameter `n_estimators`. and each such base-learner will be fit with randomly(or by other sampling method that user chooses) samples `subsample` percentage of the data, correct?

Comment: 1. The number of base learners built. 2. Forget the blogs. Read the relevant chapter (Chapt. 10) from [Elements of Statistical Learning](https://hastie.su.domains/ElemStatLearn/) and ask questions about what you don't understand. 3. Correct.

Comment: Sure @usεr11852, I will read that chapter. thanks for your time and all the answers to my questions in comments.

Answer (score 3):

I found other answers are confusing. Here is my understanding. XGBoost trees estimate the residual from the previous tree (we set a base_score as the 0th tree residual). When subsample is defined (rather than default 1.0), each tree is trained using the subsampled data, and each tree computes the residuals of all data; this makes sure you have all residuals to subsample for consequent trees. n_estimators are the number of your trees; it is not a bad idea to think of it as the iteration number in DNN, because you can also early stop the training before all trees are trained using `early_stopping_rounds` hpyerparameter. Hope it helps.